# "Order by" works in Console but doesn't work in Stored Procedures

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-order-by, informix

I've a problem executing a Stored Procedure in Informix. I'm doing a simple query that it doesn't work. This is the query:

```
SELECT 
    first 1 field1, 
    date1 
FROM 
    historia_t 
WHERE 
    field3     = 1 
    AND field4 = 1 
    AND date1 BETWEEN (CURRENT - 1 UNITS YEAR) AND CURRENT 
ORDER BY 
    field1 desc
```

If I execute the query in DbVisualizer I don't have any problem but if I execute the query in Informix(With stored procedures) I get a sintaxis error in the line with **" AND date1 BETWEEN (CURRENT - 1 UNITS YEAR) AND CURRENT " .** But the real problem it's in **ORDER BY field1 desc;**

I don't know why, but sometimes Stored Procedures return errors when you use Order by in them.

Note: Fields are invented because I think they aren't important for the problem.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: If I put the statement rounded by a FOR EACH, the query works. It's like if Informix expect several results and force me to put it within FOR EACH. I don't understand it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run a SELECT statement via DB-Access or equivalent, the program takes care of creating a cursor, opening it, fetching the data, closing the cursor, and freeing up the resources used.

Inside a stored procedure, you have to manage this processing.  The FOREACH loop does that automatically.  If you're using dynamic SQL, there are other statements you can use.

If a SELECT statement may return more than one row, you need the cursor management.  If the SELECT statement returns just a single row, you can specify which variable should receive the result. I observe that ORDER BY is immaterial when the SELECT returns a single row — if you have an ORDER BY, there'll be a strong presumption that the query might return more than one row.

For example, this stored procedure works (and returns `syssynonyms`):

```
create procedure fk2() returning varchar(128) as tabname;
    define t varchar(128);
    select tabname into t from informix.systables where tabid = 9;
    return t;
end procedure;
```

But where there's more than one row, you need:

```
create procedure fk3() returning varchar(128) as tabname;
    define t varchar(128);
    foreach select tabname into t
              from informix.systables
             where tabid between 4 and 10
             order by tabname   # No semicolon permitted (don't ask!)
        return t with resume;
    end foreach;
end procedure;
```

This returns:

```
syscolauth
sysdepend
syssynonyms
syssyntable
systabauth
sysusers
sysviews
```

Comment: After to read all a couple of time, I undestand the explanation. I undestand how does it work but it's strange because is not explicit, although it's simple. Thanks a lot @JonathanLeffler.